# Semaphores: Permit acquired in one thread can be released from another thread - Example

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to think about an example for the statement 'permit acquired in one thread and released from another thread'.

My understanding about Semaphore is, it maintains a set of Permits. A thread should acquire a permit before going over the critical section and then Permits decremented by one. Once the thread is done with the critical section it releases the permit and Permits are incremented by one.
Examples:
1. ATM machines, with a security guard who allow people based on the availability of the machine. As many machines those many are the permits. One customer acquires one ATM machine and then releases it once he/she is done.
2. Counters in the bank wherein the customer is notified if a counter is free then he/she may go and talk to the executive at the counter and get things done. As many counters those many are the permits.

So, What could be simple scenario/example wherein a permit acquired by one thread is released by other thread?

Answer (score 1):

Your ATM example is a good one. Say customers enter through one door and exit through another and each door is managed by a thread.

Or, to take a more typical example, imagine that you have only a limited number of connections to a database. A thread has to wait to start handling a request until it gets a connection to a database. Then that thread sends a request to the database. But you can't make any further forward progress until you get a reply to the database. Does it make sense to force a thread to wait around to get the reply from the database just so the same thread that took ownership of the database connection can release it?

It makes more sense to let whatever thread happens to be running when the database reply is received handle it. And then that thread can release the connection, regardless of what thread happened to be running when ownership of the connection was taken.

Think a bit abstractly about this model:
1. Thread takes ownership of resource.
2. Thread uses resource.
3. Thread releases ownership of resource.

That's great, but what if step 2 is better handled by more than one thread? Then it becomes an extra effort to ensure step 3 is executed by the same thread as step 1.